# query posts by ACF field not working

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

There are plenty of topics related to mine, but I still haven't found a solution. I'm trying to query posts by ACF field (radio button) and it seems that the meta_query gets completely ignored. It returns all the posts, instead of only those matching the criteria. I have tried using the field key instead of field name, other comparisons, etc. nothing seems to work. Hope you have an idea of what may be wrong! Here's my code:

```
<?php

    $post_args = array(
        'post_type'      => 'products',
        'posts_per_page' => - 1,
        'status'         => 'publish',
        'meta_query'     => array(
            'relation' => 'AND',
            array(
                'meta_key'   => 'product_taste',
                'meta_value' => array( 'cold' ),
                'compare'    => 'IN',
            ),
            array(
                'meta_key'   => 'product_served',
                'meta_value' => array( 'grated' ),
                'compare'    => 'IN'
            )

        ),
    );
    $query     = new WP_Query( $post_args );

    if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
        while ( $query->have_posts() ) : ?>
            <?php
            $query->the_post();
            ?>

            <h5>
                <?php the_title(); ?>
            </h5>

        <?php endwhile ?>
        <?php wp_reset_postdata();
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: Does it work if you use only one of the meta_query arrays, if you include only the product_taste meta query?

Comment: It only works when I don't use meta_query array, but simply declaring the meta_key, meta_value and compare. So it only works outside meta_query. But I need the "AND" relationship

Comment: There are issues querying ACF data using arrays and `IN`. There are a few ways around it, depending on what you need to do. Do you only need to search for a single value per meta_key (e.g. just 'cold' for 'product_taste')?

Comment: Yes, because it's a radio button :)

Comment: Good! That makes it easier :) Give me a minute to put together an answer for something that should work...

Comment: any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. **Use 'key' and 'value' in the 'meta_query' array**

You don't need to use `meta_key` and `meta_value` in a meta_query... you only use those directly in the $args array. If you are adding a meta_query array, you just use `key` and `value`, e.g.

```
$post_args = array(
    [...]
    'meta_query'     => array(
        array(
            'key'      => 'product_taste',
            'value'    => 'cold',
            'compare'  => 'LIKE',
        ),
    [...]
```

2. **Querying serialised data with an array of values**

There can also be issues using `'compare' => 'IN'` with an array of values, when you are trying to query ACF data, because the ACF data can be serialised in the database (e.g. if data is in a repeater).

As you will only ever search for a single value, you can use `LIKE` instead of `IN`.

**Putting these together**

```
$post_args = array(
    'post_type'      => 'products',
    'posts_per_page' => - 1,
    'status'         => 'publish',
    'meta_query'     => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'key'   => 'product_taste',
            'value' => 'cold',
            'compare'    => 'LIKE',
        ),
        array(
            'key'   => 'product_served',
            'value' => 'grated',
            'compare'    => 'LIKE'
        )
    ),
);
$query     = new WP_Query( $post_args );
```

**If the data is serialized** and you have values that could return multiple matches (e.g. `LIKE 'cold'` would match words like "cold", "colder","coldest"), then try adding a semicolon (`;`) at the end of the value, e.g.

```
    [...]
        array(
            'key'   => 'product_taste',
            'value' => 'cold;', // add ; to the end of the value
            'compare'    => 'LIKE',
        ),
        array(
            'key'   => 'product_served',
            'value' => 'grated;', // add ; to the end of the value
            'compare'    => 'LIKE'
        )
    [...]
```

This will work when the values are serialised in the database, because each item will be separated by a semicolon.

Comment: No effect :| It's like the meta_query is completely ignored

Comment: @ValeriaMelinte Ooooh hang on! I think I've just realised the problem! Give me a sec to confirm before I say for sure....

Comment: oh no, wait! So it works if I use "key" and "value" without the semicolon! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Glad it works! Yes you only need the semicolon if the data is serialised in the database. ACF can serialise the data depending on what type the field is. I'll update the answer to highlight that you only need the semicolon if its serialised, just in case any one else has the same problem :)